# Why am i getting error BC42104 Variable is used before it is assigned?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I can't figure out why i keep getting this warning message for the following variables: xlApp, xlWorkBooks, xlWorkSheet, xlWorkSheets, xlWorkBook.

```
    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    'PRE-PROCESSING VALIDATIONS
    Button2.Visible = False
    Button6.Visible = False

    If perennialcounter + annualcounter >= 6 Then
        MsgBox("No more files can be loaded")
        GoTo BypassThis
    End If

    'select and open file

    'file selection box and error handling for no file selected/cancel button
    TempOpenFileDialog.Title = "Select an Input File"
    If Testing = True Then
        TempOpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = TestingFileDefaultDirectory
    Else
        TempOpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = TallySheetOrderFileDefaultDirectory
    End If
    TempOpenFileDialog.Multiselect = False
    TempOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    tempfilepath = TempOpenFileDialog.FileName()
    tempfile = Path.GetFileName(tempfilepath)
    If tempfilepath = "" Then
        GoTo BypassThis
    End If

    'open file
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkSheets As Excel.Worksheets = Nothing
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
    xlWorkBooks.Open(tempfilepath)
    If Testing = True Then
        xlApp.Visible = True
    Else
        xlApp.Visible = False
    End If
    xlWorkBooks(tempfile).Activate()
    xlWorkSheet = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    'lots and lots of code...
bypassthis:
    'close excel (save) and release objects
    xlhwnd = xlApp.Hwnd    '<------ warning here
    ProcIDxl = 0
    xproc = Process.GetProcessById(ProcIDxl)
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(xlhwnd, ProcIDxl)

    xlWorkBooks(tempfile).Close(True)    '<------ warning here
    xlApp.Application.Quit()

    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)    '<------ warning here
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheets)    '<------ warning here
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)    '<------ warning here
    releaseObject(xlWorkBooks)
    releaseObject(xlApp)

    xlWorkSheet = Nothing
    xlWorkSheets = Nothing
    xlWorkBook = Nothing
    xlWorkBooks = Nothing
    xlApp = Nothing


    'show/reshow buttons
    If perennialcounter + annualcounter > 0 Then
        Button6.Visible = True
        Button6.Text = "Process"
    End If
    Button2.Visible = True
    ProgressBar7.Visible = False
    ProgressBar8.Visible = False
End Sub
```

There is nothing in the code that would push it out of the sub or skip the line where the first error is.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Because you declare those variables *after* you use 'GoTo' and using it in 'bypassthis'. Btw...you should never ever use 'GoTo'. Never.

Comment: What should I use instead of "GoTo"?

Comment: create separete functions one called if `tempfilepath`is empty and one if it`s not

Comment: @JonMilliken Using GoTo is discouraged because it can create situations exactly like what you are experiencing. I would not say that you should never use it - but if you use it you should know exactly what you are doing and why before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you should repeat your test on tempfilepath in the bypassthis block...

```
bypassthis:

If tempfilepath <> "" Then

'close excel (save) and release objects
    xlhwnd = xlApp.Hwnd    '<------ warning here
    ProcIDxl = 0
    xproc = Process.GetProcessById(ProcIDxl)
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(xlhwnd, ProcIDxl)

    xlWorkBooks(tempfile).Close(True)    '<------ warning here
    xlApp.Application.Quit()

    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)    '<------ warning here
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheets)    '<------ warning here
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)    '<------ warning here
    releaseObject(xlWorkBooks)
    releaseObject(xlApp)

    xlWorkSheet = Nothing
    xlWorkSheets = Nothing
    xlWorkBook = Nothing
    xlWorkBooks = Nothing
    xlApp = Nothing

End If
```

As Alex B. mentioned in the comments, please be careful with GoTo - it is what caused your issue.